# Registering phantomjs node on Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-grid

I have already run my tests in parallel on Selenium Grid using multiple chrome instances. How would I set up Selenium Grid so that I can run my tests using multiple phantomjs instances instead of chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Docker container resource on GitHub:

https://github.com/madhavajay/selenium-node-phantomjs